# How do I drop my knife?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'd like to test out nades in CSGO but I would like to do so without having to switch back from the knife to the nade. I have infinite ammo so I can test out popflashes and smokes.

How do I drop my knife so that I only have nades in my inventory?

Comment: there must be an option because if you know the maps surf_* most of them have worked it out to give you no weapons .. it looks realy funny.

Comment: Binding the individual grenade type to a key might make it a little less tedious (you may already be doing this).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Enter the following command into the console:

- as a **CT**: `mp_ct_default_melee ""`
- as a **T**: `mp_t_default_melee ""`

After that, enter `mp_restartgame 1`. Done, and now you will spawn without a knife.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, and I may not be, there is no way that you can. On some servers there are plugins that are ran for you to lose all weapons, or for you to have a certain set of weapons.

I've never heard of this happening in solo with bots though, [here is the list that has every command.](http://pastebin.com/y9rJ9SEH)

Answer (score 1):

You can drop your knife with the console command "mp_drop_knife_enable".

Answer (score -2):

simple answer: you can't drop your knife.